# ORMLite and setting session date variables

Tags: java, oracle, ormlite

What is the correct way of running a session formatting query via ORMLite? The reason that I am setting session formatting is that the queries that I run never retrieve any results and I keep getting an absurd error (you can see it below).

This is what I am currently doing to set up the session format:

```
String sqlSession = "alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';";
Conn.My_Dao().queryRaw(sqlSession);
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not perform raw query for
    alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

The reason I am doing that (as I mentioned earlier) - is that for any query that I run I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems parsing default date string '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
    using 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'
```

I had experienced something similar with Oracle SQL in the past (with an old PHP project to be precise) and I just handled it by setting the session formating to the aforementioned one.

However, I agree that this might not be the most elegant solution to this problem. What would the best way to handle it?

Comment: Reminder to accept my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not perform raw query for alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

In the future, make sure to post more of the exception when you get one.  I suspect that there was a "Caused by" line later on in the exception that said something about this not being a *query*.

I'm guessing that you should use the [`Dao.executeRaw(...)` method](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#executeRaw-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-) instead of [`Dao.queryRaw(...)`](https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-).  Queries really need to be `select` statements which return results.